# dispatch_sync onto main thread from CVDisplayLink callback

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-video

I'm animating a variable using `CVDisplayLink` on macOS, and I'm curious if there's any reason to **not** use `dispatch_sync` from the display link's thread (assuming I'm only "driving" one animation per display link). Anyone know?

It seems to work fine. I tried `dispatch_async` first (onto the main thread, btw) and I noticed how frames would get skipped due to the thread switching being too slow, I guess.

When using `dispatch_sync`, no frames are skipped, but (of course) the time between display link "ticks" has increased. I figure it's no big deal since the display link will wait until the next vsync before ticking again.

I guess, either way, there will be times where the display refreshes before the main thread can update in response to the display link, but I'm still curious if one approach is better than the other. Thanks!

PS: Maybe using a `NSTimer` would be better? Since that would let me execute directly on the main thread, instead of using GCD from another thread. I assume that would be unable to vsync, but idk.

Comment: Hmm... I think I found my answer. Calling `CVDisplayLinkStop` from the main thread leads to a deadlock when using `dispatch_sync`.

Comment: It feels wrong to say, but it seems like there's no way to align with vsync on the main thread (on macOS at least).

Comment: In the case of animation, it looks like "dispatch sources" are the preferred way of responding on the main thread, since events are coalesced.